# The possible numbers which can be re-position

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I am trying to switch the given set of number into every possible cases. For example, the number set is [0,1,2]

The possible numbers which can be built by this set are
 - 012
 - 021
 - 102
 - 120
 - 210
 - 201

How am I supposed to write a javascript code to compile a result like this.

Remark : No repeated numbers contain

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: (combo = arr => {
    if (!arr.length) return [];
    if (arr.length === 1) return [arr];
    const results = [];
    for (let index = arr.length; index--;) {
        const rest = arr.slice();
        rest.splice(index, 1);
        combo(rest).forEach(combination => {
            results.push([arr[index]].concat(combination))
        });
    }
    return results;
})([0, 1, 2])

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40655572/295783